# How to write combinations using double summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, summation-method

I am not entirely sure whether I got the point right, so could you please check, whether I wrote the following correctly?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{\binom{n}{i}}{j}$$

The result should be for $n=2$ this

$$\binom{\binom{2}{1}}{1} + \binom{\binom{2}{1}}{2} + \binom{\binom{2}{2}}{1} + \binom{\binom{2}{2}}{2}$$

Comment: That is the correct expression of the double-sum for $n=2$.

Comment: @Jam Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-sum is equivalent to $$\underbrace{\left[\binom{\binom{n}{1}}{1}+\binom{\binom{n}{1}}{2}+\ldots+\binom{\binom{n}{1}}{n}\right]}_{i=1}+\underbrace{\left[\ldots\right]}_{i=2}+\ldots+\underbrace{\left[\binom{\binom{n}{n}}{1}+\binom{\binom{n}{n}}{2}+\ldots+\binom{\binom{n}{n}}{n}\right]}_{i=n}$$

So for $n=2$, it would have been

$$\underbrace{\left[\binom{\binom{2}{1}}{1}+\binom{\binom{2}{1}}{2}\right]}_{i=1}+\underbrace{\left[\binom{\binom{2}{2}}{1}+\binom{\binom{2}{2}}{2}\right]}_{i=2}=4$$